# Change MasterPage with VS. Doesn't change the site

Tags: master-page, html

I edited my masterpage with VS. I deploy the solution but I see the old masterpage. My Masterpager is

```
<File Path="MasterPages\MY.master" Url="MY.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
  <Property Name="Title" Value="MY Master Page"/>
  <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15"/>
</File>
```

How can I tell SharePoint to use my new version of the MasterPage ?

Comment: Have you published it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a feature to attach this master page to your site.

```
SPWeb objWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    objWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    objWeb.MasterUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(objWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "/_catalogs/masterpage/MY.master");

                    objWeb.CustomMasterUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(objWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "/_catalogs/masterpage/MY.master");
                    objWeb.Update();
                    objWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Also try to validate your master page by:
http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/apply-custom-master-pages-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I have to put the code in the EventReceiver of th Feature ?  
  I try the code :   

    `$masterPage = "mywebsite.com/_catalogs/masterpage/MY.master";
    $WebUrl = "mywebsite.com";

    $objWeb = Get-SPWeb($WebUrl);
    $objWeb.MasterUrl = $masterPage;
    $objWeb.CustomMasterUrl = $masterPage;
    $objWeb.Update();
`

It say the MY.master doesn't exist ... but i can see it in my browser

Comment: Are you using powershell? Try this:  $masterPage = "/_catalogs/masterpage/MY.master"

Comment: I think powershell more easy just for one time. Now the code doesn't say the masterpage doesn't exist but i don't see the change in my page Index.aspx, i see the older html code.

Comment: Did you set objWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

Comment: Also check other sharepoint pages like Home.aspx if master page is updated there or not?

Comment: AllowUnsafeUpdates already = true. I try an another page, the masterpage is not update. I publish the masterpage with the code `$file.CheckIn("")
$file.Publish("")` where `$file = $web.GetFile(....)`

Comment: Also check : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/navdeepm/archive/2008/05/04/changing-masterpage-programmatically-for-site-collection-and-sub-sites.aspx and other link provided in solution